# Ogre game programming using TDD

Tags: c++, testing, tdd, ogre3d, ogre

I'd like to ask you if it's worth it to use the [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) concept while creating a 3D game in C++ with [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/)? I know I can use it while creating my algorithms (like path-finding, AI, paging, etc.) and the game logic, but can it be used to test the drawing side? I mean if the proper objects are drawn, if the proper animation is set & used and a lot of other "things" that I don't want to enumerate.

I've been searching about it for days but *I haven't found the answer that I can accept*.
Basically which part of game development should be done with TDD and which part not? Does 3D game development need TDD?

Comment: Was it really necessary to link to TDD *three times*?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question but using TDD to create algorithms may not be as useful as you think: http://ravimohan.blogspot.com/2007/04/learning-from-sudoku-solvers.html

Comment: @ssg So you say I should plan/specificate my algorithms as well as I can and write unit tests than using TDD? Why is it better?

Answer (score 1):

Ogre uses so many Singletons and other global state, I find it difficult to see how you could implement meaningful tests for it- even ignoring the difficulty of testing the accuracy of a rendered image.

Comment: @Klaim: That doesn't make them meaningful- or, more relevantly, even if they are, that they were written in a reasonable amount of time and effort.